# Multi-level menu in laravel 5.1 - loops

Tags: php, css, foreach, menu, laravel-5.1

I am a little bit new with laravel 5.1 framework. Last couple of days I create my database (insert, update, delete) for dynamic menu I want to create. I connect with default layout in which i put menu. From route code looks like this.

```
View::composer('layouts.default',function($view){
    $menus = Menu::where('parent_id',0)->orderBy('order')->get();
    $submenus = Menu::where('parent_id','!=',0)->get();
    $view->with(compact('menus','submenus'));
});
```

In main menu are items with parent_id = 0. Submenu items have parent_id = id, and soo on.

I want to display correct but when I hover main menu items that dont have items, css block appear, becouse i didnt make good if condition. Is there any way to do this?

Code in view look like this.

```
@foreach($menus as $menu)
                    <li class="dropdown {!! (Request::is('typography') || Request::is('advancedfeatures') || Request::is('grid') ? 'active' : '') !!}"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> {!! $menu->title !!}</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        @foreach($submenus as $submenu)
                                @if($submenu->parent_id === $menu->id)
                                <li><a href="{{ URL::to('typography') }}">{!! $submenu->title !!}</a>
                                    @foreach($submenus as $smenu)
                                            @if($smenu->parent_id === $submenu->id)
                                                <ul class="dropdown-submenu" role="menu">
                                                    <li><a href="{{ URL::to('typography') }}">{!! $smenu->title !!}</a>
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>
                                            @endif
                                    @endforeach
                                </li>
                            @endif
                            @endforeach
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    @endforeach
```

One more question is how to take only one value from **Menu model** for example **id** that can be used to point only one submenu.

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply by using recursion. I removed html classes for readability.

Note: Set NULL parent_id for root items.

Add this relation to your Menu Model.

```
function childs()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Namespace\Menu','parent_id', 'id');
}
```

In your controller get the menus who has no parent.

```
  $menus = Menu::whereNull('parent_id')->orderBy('order')->get();
```

Then display them in your view.

```
<ul>
  @foreach($menus as $menu)
     <li>
         {!! $menu->title !!}
         @include('childItems')//recursion view
     </li>
 @endforeach
</ul>
```

And this is what your childItems.blade.php will look like.

```
 <ul>
    @foreach($menu->childs as $menu)
       <li>
          {!! $menu->title !!}
          @include('childItems')//call itself for deeper relations.
       </li>
    @endforeach
 </ul>
```

That's it.